# yii2 unit testing having error of call to a member function getDb() on null

Tags: php, unit-testing, yii2, codeception

```
<?php

namespace tests\codeception\engine;

use engine\components\BaseException;

use engine\components\BaseService;

use engine\modules\account\models\AccUser;

use engine\modules\account\models\AccUserActivity;

use engine\modules\account\services\AccountService;

use yii\db\Connection;



class AccountServiceTest extends \Codeception\TestCase\Test

{

    protected $tester;

    protected function _before()
    {
    }

    protected function _after()
    {
    }

    public function getDb()
    {
        $connection=Yii::$app->getDb();
    }

    public function testIsEmailAvailable()
    {
        $account = AccountService::model();


        // 1. Existing email check
        $email = 'alk@gmail.com';
        $this->assertEquals(true, $account->isEmailAvailable($email));

        // 2. New email check
        $email = 'arulvel@gmail.com';
        $this->assertEquals(false, $account->isEmailAvailable($email));

        // 3. Not an email check only character
        $email = 'arulvel';
        $this->assertEquals(false, $account->isEmailAvailable($email));

        // 4. Not an email check only numbers
        $email = '549876315';
        $this->assertEquals(false, $account->isEmailAvailable($email));

        // 5. Empty check
        $email = '';
        $this->assertEquals(false, $account->isEmailAvailable($email));

        return true;
    }

}
```

while running the test it showing an error like this

Trying to test is email available (AccountServiceTest::testIsEmailAvailable)...

PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getDb() on null in

/var/www/html/rewards/shopsup-rewards-

web/htdocs/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/ActiveRecord.php on line 133

FATAL ERROR. TESTS NOT FINISHED.
Call to a member function getDb() on null

when accessing that ActiveRecord.php on line 133 it is like

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMiHV.png)

is there any configuration need to be made??

Comment: have you tried ? `$connection=Yii::$app->db;`

Comment: yes...i tried that one also...but can't able to find the error

Comment: have you created test db for unit testing?

Comment: can you explain me how could it be done??i am new to this one

Answer (score 0):

From [Github](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/7836)

> In case of unit tests it's your responsibility to create application
>   instance.

From [Yii Forum](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/68585-call-to-a-member-function-getdb-on-null/)

> You can set up the db component ?

https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-codeception/blob/master/TestCase.php#L36

```
class TestCase extends Test
{
    use FixtureTrait;
    /**
     * @var array|string the application configuration that will be used for creating an application instance for each test.
     * You can use a string to represent the file path or path alias of a configuration file.
     * The application configuration array may contain an optional `class` element which specifies the class
     * name of the application instance to be created. By default, a [[\yii\web\Application]] instance will be created.
     */
    public $appConfig = '@tests/codeception/config/unit.php';
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on this, Muhammed? How do I crate an application instance?

Answer (score 0):

If you use Yii2 Advanced Template.

edit your unit.suite.yml and add "orm" into part array.

eg.

```
suite_namespace: backend\tests\unit
actor: UnitTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - Yii2:
            part: [orm, email, fixtures]
        - Asserts
```